# unable to set property 'visibility' or 'display'

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist box in the datagrid and I need to hide or show it. I can get the element.  However I get an error 'Unable to set property 'display' of undefined or null reference. when I want to hide it. I tried to use visibility and it has same type of error too.  Would someone show me how to do it. Thanks

My control:

```
<asp:dropdownList ID="dropID" runat="server" cssclass="selectColor w175 show"/>
```

The class in my style sheet:

```
.show   {
display: normal;
}    

.selectColor {

color: #333333; }       


.w175 { width:175px; }
```

my javascript function:

```
function NeedChange(id) {
 var dropID = document.getElementById(id);
  if (dropID!=undefined ){
    //dropID.style.visibility="hidden";
    dropID.style.display='none';
}
 }
```

Comment: what is *normal*? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Well how do you call NeedChange?

Comment: Are you using console.log to test these things? Once you've declared dropID, throw a console.log in and see if it returns anything.

Also you can refactor your condition to be 'if(dropID)' - which will be false if null or undefined.

Comment: "Normal" is not a valid value for the *display* property, see [*W3C CSS/Properties/display*](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display).

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function NeedChange(id) {
var dropID = document.getElementById(id);
if (dropID!=undefined ){
//dropID.style.visibility="hidden";
$("#dropID").removeClass("show");
}
}
```

Comment: I got an error "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'removeClass'

Comment: @user819774 : I have made some changes

Comment: And make sure u have jquery added before this function

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that ID `dropID` does not exist on the page, you javascript cannot find it. asp.net turn the ID's in elements that repeat data (GridView, ListView, Repeater etc) into something like this: `ContentPane1_GridView1_DropDownList1_0`.
So in order to show/hide a specific DropDownList you need to know the row number. The rest of the ID you can get with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myElement = "<%= GridView1.ClientID %>_dropID_" + rowNumber;
    // becomes ContentPane1_GridView1_dropID_24

    document.getElementById(myElement).style.display = "none";
</script>
```

The tricky part is getting the row number. That will depend on your grid design and why and how you want to hide the dropdown;